# Contextual Search: Classifying shopping products

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification

I have got a new task(not traditional) from my client, It is something about machine learning.
As I have never been to "machine learning" except some little Data Mining stuff so I need your help.

My task is to Classify a product present on any Shopping Site, on the basis of gender(whom the product belongs to),agegroup etc, the training data we can have is the product's Title, Keywords(available in the html of the product page), and product description.

I did a lot of R&D , I found Image Recog APIs(cloudsight,vufind) that returned the details of the product image but that did not full fill the need, used google suggestqueries, searched out many machine learning algorithms and finally...

I came to know about the "Decision Tree Learning Algorithm" but cannot figure out, how it is applicable to my problem.
I tried out the "PlayingTennis" dataset but couldn't make the sense what to do.

Can you give me some direction that from where to start this journey? Should I focus on The Decision Tree Learning algorithm or Is there any other algorithm you would suggest I should focus on to categorize the products on the basis of context?

If you say , I would share in detail about what things I searched about to solve my problem.

Comment: In what categories do you want to categorize products? What keywords do you have in product page?

Comment: I want to categorize them on the basis of gender i.e analyzing the product title/description , I want to evaluate that the product is for male or female.

Comment: Do you have a training dataset? If yes, are training instances in this set are labeled with expected gender? E.g. if you have a a product in your dataset, do you know if this product is for male or female?

Comment: According to human sense, I know that this product is for women or men, like "John Varvatos USA Peace Polo - Slim Fit" shirt from bloomingdales , is for men, that is what I know not the computer.
Following is the link for this product,
http://www1.bloomingdales.com/shop/product/john-varvatos-usa-peace-polo-slim-fit?ID=787264

Now, I want the computer ,to figure out the gender this product belongs to using the description and other data present on the link. I am finding a way but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to do the following:

1. Go through items in your dataset and classify them manually (decide for which gender each item is). Store each decision so that you would be able to somehow link each item in an original dataset with a target class.
2. Develop an algorithm for converting each item from your dataset into a feature vector. This algorithm should be able to convert each item in your original dataset in a vector of numbers (more about how to do it later).
3. Convert all your dataset with appropriate classes into a dataset that would look like this:

Feature_1, Feature_2, Feature_3, ..., Gender

value_1, value_2, value_3, ... male

It would be a good decision to store it in CSV file since you would be able to load it and process in different machine learning tools (More about those later).

4. Load dataset you've created at step 3 in machine learning tool of your choice and try to come up with the best model that can classify items in your dataset by gender.
5. Store model created at step 4. It will be part of your production system.
6. Develop a production code that can convert an unclassified product, create feature vector out of it and pass this feature vector to the model you've saved at step 5. The result of this operation should be a predicted gender.

**Details**

If there too many items (say tens of thousands) in your original dataset it may be impractical to classify them yourself. What you can do is to use [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) to simplify your task. If you are unable to use it (the last time I've checked you had to have a USA address to use it) you can just classify few hundreds of items to start working on your model and classify the rest to improve accuracy of your classification (the more training data you use the better the accuracy, but up to a certain point)

**How to extract features from a dataset**

If keyword has form like tag=true/false, it's a boolean feature.
If keyword has form like tag=42, it's a numerical one or [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_data). For example it can be price value or price range (0-10, 10-50, 50-100, etc.)
If keyword has form like tag=string_value you can convert it [into a categorical value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable)
A class (gender) is simply boolean value 0/1
You can experiment a bit with how you extract your features, since it may influence the result accuracy.

**How to extract features from product description**

There are different ways to convert a text into a feature vector. Look for [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) algorithms or something similar.

**Machine learning tools**

You can use one of existing machine learning libraries and hack some code that loads your CSV dataset, trains a model and checks the accuracy, but at first I would suggest to use something like [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). It has more or less intuitive UI and you can quickly start to experiment with different machine learning algorithms, convert different features in your dataset from string to categories, or from real values to ordinal values, etc. Good thing about Weka is that it has Java API, so you can automate all the process of data conversion, train models programmatically, etc.

**What algorithms to choose**

I would suggest to use decision tree algorithms like [C4.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm). It's fast and show good results on wide range of machine learning tasks. Additionally you can use [ensemble of classifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning). There are various algorithms that can combine several algorithms like (google for boosting or random forest to find out more) usually they give better results, but work more slowly (since you need to run a single feature vector through several algorithms.

One another trick that you can use to make your algorithm more accurate is to use models that work on different sets of features (say one algorithm uses features extracted from tags and another algorithm uses data extracted from product description). You can then combine them using algorithms like [stacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Stacking) to come up with a final result.

For classification on the basis of features extracted from text, you can try to use [Naive Bayes algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) or [SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine). They both show good results in text classification.

Answer (score 0):

Do consider Support Vector Classifier (SVC), or for Google's sake the Support Vector Machine (SVM). If You have a large training set (which I suspect) search for implementations that are "fast" or "scalable".

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, let me check and get back to you.

Comment: Getting back, Can you please explain in detail focusing on my problem i.e to classify any shopping product like "Polo T-Shirt" with some description in male/female categories.
Actually, your answer is very much general, and I wanted some particular one.

What algorithm should help me?
What should be the way of doing this?

Comment: @SarimJavaidKhan how did this project go? Any link to your work?